# Android: crash when accessing user class from thread

Tags: java, android

When I try to call one of my custom classes from a Thread constructor I get an exception, I've no idea why...

My Main app boils down to:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements OnTouchListener,    SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
   class GameThread extends Thread
   {
      private GfxData   m_GraphicsData;

      public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context, Handler handler)
      {
         Log.i("****", "GameThread::GameThread");
         m_GraphicsData.InitGfx();;
         Log.i("****", "GameThread::end");
      }
... (other required functions)
}
```

My GfxData class (the entire file)

```
package mypackage.stuff;

public class GfxData 
{
   public GfxData()
   {
   }

   public void InitGfx()
   {
   }
}
```

The class GameThread never reaches the end of the constructor; I've removed virtually everything from my GfxData class (which I'd intended to pass the context to so I could use it to manage my resources) but still it causes a crash; however if I remove the InitGfx() call everything is fine

I'm bamboozled! Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: GfxData doesn't seem to be static, are you sure, you don't need to initialize it? (e.g. `private GfxData m_GraphicsData = new GfxData`) - it would help if you could post the exception you're getting.

Comment: Ahhh! That would be it; thank you. You can tell I usually code in C++ can't you?

Comment: Mmmh ... no ;) And if that really was the problem I'll wish my rough guess was an answer instead of just a comment. Oh, well...

Comment: @Select0r: It's not to late to add an answer with the same text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GfxData` doesn't seem to be static, are you sure, you don't need to initialize it?
e.g. `private GfxData m_GraphicsData = new GfxData`

it would help if you could post the exception you're getting.

Comment: Just to be clear, static members need to be initialized too; it's just that they need to be initialized only once, no matter how many times the constructor is called.